# Intellij doesn't show compile time error

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I am unable to find any error in Intellij even after making mistakes

For example: If i write following statement

```
  String str1 =new String("Shoaib")
```

It should show red color stating that ; is missing.But it is unable to do so.
I may have change something internally

What i need to do to work above issue

Comment: Did you enable `File` | `Power Save Mode` by accident?

Comment: Do you have File | Power Save Mode enabled?

Comment: It was enabled. But i disabled now. Then also same problem persist

Comment: It worked any one can add this as answer. And i will accept that

Comment: Debug is not applying for Test classes.Any solution??

Answer (score 1):

To fix this just disable the power saver mode and add the live edit plugin. When you disable the power saver mode it will automatically prompt in right bottom corner for installing the live edit plugin just click yes on it and restart your intellij, It will work as expected.